# Maven Doesn't Seem to Pass Arguments to JVM

Tags: java, android, maven, out-of-memory

I'm trying to compile an Android application that depends on OrmLite and whatever I do I still receive the OutOfMemory error.

The reason why I think Maven doesn't pass any arguments regarding the heap size is I can only see the following in its output:

/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -jar /Users/mikhail.borozdin/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools/lib/dx.jar --dex --output=/Users/mikhail.borozdin/Documents/workspace/AndroidOrmLiteTest/target/classes.dex

How did I try to pass arguments to JVM?

- export MAVEN_OPTS=-Xmx2048m
- mvn -X install -DargLine="-Xmx2048m"
- Setting  for my plug-in in pom.xml
- Setting  for my plug-in in pom.xml

Neither of these worked.

Comment: Try setup JAVA_OPTS instead of MAVEN_OPTS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the project you're building is using the [android-maven-plugin](http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/), you want to set the [dex mojo configuration](http://maven-android-plugin-m2site.googlecode.com/svn/dex-mojo.html#dex) in the maven pom.xml file, eg:

```
<dex>
  <jvmArguments>
    <jvmArgument>-Xms256m</jvmArgument>
    <jvmArgument>-Xmx512m</jvmArgument>
  </jvmArguments>
</dex>
```

Here's an example from a complete pom.xml file:

https://github.com/rtyley/agit/blob/a014c970/pom.xml#L116-121

Note that the specific xml for dex configuration evolved a fair bit in the run-up to release of android-maven-plugin version 3.0.0 (which has *lots* of other crucial improvements) - I would recommend ensuring that you are using this version and that the configuration is definitely using the `<dex>` node.

The android-maven-plugin [will use a 1GB heap by default](https://github.com/jayway/maven-android-plugin/pull/81) in versions post-v3.0.0 (not yet released at the time of writing).

Comment: This is the correct answer. I wrote the code for those parameters and use it every day..

Comment: Thanks @Roberto! That version thing just saved me! I tried <dex><jvmArguments> before, but it didn't work because I didn't specify a version.